# How to setup WebStorm 2018 to refresh Chrome when Node Express app change

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, webstorm, nodemon

I am using WebStorm 2018.3 and Chrome for development.
I was searching for way how to refresh Chrome window when Node Express app change.

I am using nodemon to restart server.
How to setup WebStorm (or is there any other tool?) to a achieve live-reload like with for example React+webpack-dev-server

Comment: you can try using [live edit](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/live-editing.html)

Comment: @lena not working